# DateTime.Now issue in Windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, wp7test

I am developing a windows phone 7 application. In my application user can make purchases. After purchasing we send the purchase details to our database server for future reference. The purchase details include date and time of purchase. Now am using DateTime.Now to take the current time and date of purchase in phone. But my doubt is, if the phone's date and time is wrong at the time of purchase , then I will get wrong details. So how can I handle this ?
Thanks

Comment: You can't afaik. Use the created_at time in db for each row :)

Comment: You can't from the phone, but you might be able to use the server to grab the server's current time on insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by getting the current date from the server side.